# Preg_replace dynamic

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, preg-replace, return

Keys, and values mysql.

```
$valores[$codigo] = "<img src=\"template/" . $template . "/smiles/" . $smile . "\" border=\"0\"/>";
$arrayKeys  =   array_keys($valores);
$arrayValues    =   array_values($valores);
return preg_replace($arrayKeys, $arrayValues, $coment);
```

error, Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: No ending delimiter ':' found.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: What is $codigo? what is $coment? What do you want to do? I don't understand the question.

Por los nombres de las variables supongo que hablas español. Creo que no se está entendiendo qué es lo que quieres hacer realmente. Creo que deberías reformular la pregunta explicando un poco más.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) instead.

**Edit :**

You just need to replace preg_replace by str_replace :

```
return str_replace($arrayKeys, $arrayValues, $coment);
```

See the documentation here [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace() - Perform a regular expression search and replace

If I understand correctly you want to replace :) with smiles images so you can do that like this:

```
<?php
    $search = array(":))",":)");
    $replace  = array("<img src=\"template/" . $template . "/smiles/laugh.jpg\" />","<img src=\"template/" . $template . "/smiles/smile.jpg\" />");
    str_replace($search, $replace, $comment);
?>
```